# Minimum Curvature Path

Tags: geometry, quadratics, curvature

Let's say we are given a closed race track with a given and constant width. I am to implement an algorithm which finds both shortest path trajectory and minimum curvature trajectory for the car.

I have found a paper [(F. Braghin et al. / Computers and Structures 86 (2008) 1503-1516)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045794908000163) which explains both the shortest path trajectory and the  minimum curvature trajectory.

I understood the shortest path equations except (8) but couldn't understand any equations in the minimum curvature path trajectory. Could someone please explain those equations?

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/444289/35416) is asking about the same paper. Since my currently accepted answer concentrates on the shortest path, not the minimum curvature one, that question is not a duplicate, but since it's about the same paper the two are definitely related and worth a cross reference in the form of this comment here.

Comment: I have already read that question and the answer. Thank you.