# Most optimal route for racecar going through a quarter-circle turn?

Tags: geometry, optimization, calculus-of-variations

The following is just a rough version of the question, which is made more clear below:

> How can it be proven/disproven that the fastest route for a racecar making a quarter-circle turn is the route given by a section of a bigger circle that intersects the outer part of the track at the start and end of the turn and intersects the inner part of the track halfway through the turn?

In the figure below, I have drawn a circle of radius $R$ so that it intersects 1) a circle with radius $r_2$ at points that are $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians apart in the circle defined by $r_2$, and 2) a smaller circle of radius $r_1$ inscribed in the one with radius $r_2$. The figure should make it clear.

I have calculated $R$ to be 
$$R=\frac{r_1^2+r_2^2-\sqrt{2}r_1r_2}{2r_1-\sqrt{2}r_2}$$
which makes sense since $R\rightarrow \infty$ as $r_1 \rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}r_2$, in which case you can draw a straight line.

Now, the length of the arc drawn out by the bigger circle from one point of intersection to the other is given as $\theta R$, where
$$\theta = 2\arctan\left(\left(2\left(\frac{R}{r_2}\right)^2-1\right)^{-1/2}\right)$$

Now returning to the question: We assume that the speed at which the racecar is going at any point in the turn is proportional to $\sqrt{r}$, where $r$ is the radius of turning at that point (i.e. the curvature at that point is $1/r$).

> For a track with constant width $r_2-r_1$ (with $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}r_2<r_1<r_2$), is the route through a quarter-circle turn that minimizes the time spent in said turn given by a section of a circle with length $\theta R$ (as seen in the figure)?

The reason I think it is given by $\theta R$ is based purely on intuition.

I guess the problem will most easily be solved using calculus of variations, as it is somewhat similar to the Brachistochrone problem (with the added constraint of the width of the track), but I don't know how to attack it.

Thanks!

[image]

**EDIT 1:** [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444289/shortest-path-and-minimum-curvature-path-implementation) addresses the more general question of finding the optimal route around a track, but has an algorithmic approach instead. If someone coincidentally has a script with such an $A*$ algorithm at hand, they could test it on a quarter-circle turn and see whether or not the route of least curvature follows the arc of a bigger circle?

**EDIT 2:** As *Jens* has suggested in the comments, some kind of speed limit should be introduced. I think it is sufficient to demand that the function given by the speed of the car should be differentiable (after all, infinite acceleration isn't very realistic).

Comment: If the speed is proportional to the square root of the turning radius, the speed would be infinite for a straight line segment. So make a path consisting of straight segments. :-)

Comment: @Jens I don't think that's necessarily true, since there would be discontinuities where those line-segments are pieced together, where the speed would be zero.

Comment: Hmmmm...could be a fair point. What's the turning radius of a 10 degree angle? My point, though, (aside from a bit of fun) was that you needed to make some constraints. For example, I think assuming that $r_2 \lt \sqrt 2 r_1$ might be a good idea.

Comment: @Jens, yes I thought that was naturel, but I'll edit to make it more clear! Thanks!

Comment: Nice! I have to ask, though, if straight segments are still allowed as long as they don't cause any discontinuities?

Comment: @Jens Sure, but I actually still think "spreading the curvature out" over the turn is more efficient - a straight line will just result in a larger curvature somewhere else, but i may be wrong.

Comment: The speed of the car isn't proportional to $\sqrt{r}$; it's proportional to $\sqrt{R}$, the turning radius. It doesn't matter what the track is doing, but how hard the car is turning. If the car follows the circular path of radius $R$, its speed will be constant.

Comment: @MarkH Using $r$ instead of $R$ was just to allow for other (all) routes to be in competition as to which one is the most efficient. In the case where the car follows the arc with length $\theta R$ (which I suspect minimizes the time spent in the turn), the curvature is $1/R$, but the best route to take may have a varying turning radius, hence the variable $r$.

Comment: The reason I asked is that if you allow line segments (with infinite speed) then a path, starting and ending as yours, but being tangent to $r_1$ from the starting point and tangent to $r_1$ from the ending point and traveling along $r_1$ in between, will have a total time of $T_{Arc} = \frac {Angle_{Arc}*r_1}{k \sqrt{r_1}}$, where $Angle_{Arc} = 2(\frac{\pi}{4}-arccos(\frac{r_1}{r_2}))$ and $k$ is the proportionality constant. And this will always be less than the time spent on your circle. I therefore suggest you make additional constraints, e.g. a max speed.

Comment: @Jens I see your point, but I don't see why it will always be less? What is required is expressed in the following WA-query, and it doesn't seem to know whether or not it is true: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt((r_1%5E2%2Br_2%5E2-sqrt(2)r_1+r_2)%2F(2r_1-sqrt(2)r_2))arctan((2(R%2Fr_2)%5E2-1)%5E(-1%2F2))%3Esqrt(r_1)(pi%2F4-arccos(r_1%2Fr_2))

Comment: Simulations in Excel (for $r_2$ ranging in increments of $0.1$ between $r_1$ and $\sqrt{2}r_1$) show it's true! :-) Seriously though, I haven't done the differentations of the equations to show it is always true because I didn't expect you to accept an answer with infinite speeds. I'll have a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: @Jens That should be good enough, thanks! I'd just rather keep the problem as simple as possible and not introduce arbitrary speed limits and such, but perhaps it is necessary. Could one perhaps just demand differentiability of the speed-function (or perhaps even accel.)? In your example, the speed goes from infinite to $\propto \sqrt{r_1}$, so it isn't smooth.